# delete from an array

Tags: php

I have an array of objects:

```
$obj = array();

// add the new items
$row = new stdClass();
$row->first = $first;
$row->last = $last;
$row->phone = $phone;

$obj[] = $row;
```

Now, if I only have the value of $last, is there a way to delete the entire $row object without specifying each key/value? 
(If it helps to understand, if it was a mysql statement it would be something like "DELETE * FROM $obj WHERE $row->last = 'Thomas' ")

thx

Comment: do you mean delete $row from $obj???

Comment: i just threw that in...if it doesn't help clarify then ignore it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the key. However, if you iterate through the array you can find it.

```
/* Your original code: */
$obj = array();

// add the new items
$row = new stdClass();
$row->first = $first;
$row->last = $last;
$row->phone = $phone;

$obj[] = $row;

/* My addition: */
$theOneToDelete = $last;
foreach ($obj as $key => $row) {
   if ($row->last == $theOneToDelete) {
      unset($obj[$key]);
      break;
   }
}
```

There may be a terser approach with some of the `array_*` functions, but this lays it out.

Answer (score 2):

Is `unset($row);` what you want? But there is no need to do that if you are just doing it to save memory...

Comment: `unset()` does not immediately free memory. Memory, in PHP, gets freed when the garbage collector deems appropriate.

Comment: I think that this will not unset the array element, merely the original object. Although physically they may, for a while, be the same object in memory (hurray for copy-on-write) at this point they are semantically separate.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
  if($obj[$key]->last == $last){
    unset($obj[$key]);
  }
}
```

Oops, I forgot to format my response as code. I'm new here! =P